# Flutter Deployment Keystore password is too short

Tags: flutter

while i developed the flutter app i just create the key paste on i got the problem is.

```
Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters
```

i attached the screen shot image below
[image]

what i tried so far i have change the key more than 10 charactor i wrote and submit but again get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to generating JKs files. try to flow those steps.

**Step 1.** Just Copy and paste this comment into your terminal Nothing has to change.

`keytool -genkey -v -keystore %userprofile%\upload-keystore.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload`

**Step 2.** Answer some questions like your screenshot.

***Note :** If haven't any info just hit the enter button But good practice is to use proper info.*

**Step 3.** When you get this line just enter `yes` and then hit the enter button.

`Is CN=Tanvir islam, OU=Anun, O=an, L=Dhaka, ST=Dhaka, C=BD correct? [no]:  yes`

Comment: i tried your one still same problem Keystore password is too short - must be at least 6 characters

Comment: @JohnPeter Most probably you are not properly entering the password. You can do this in Android Studio.  Reference :  https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing